# Is applet and application in EMV chip the same?

Tags: javacard, emv

I'm new to EMV and I'm having doubt about the use of application and applet in card. I've seen in some sites they were telling that application and applet are same.

Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you are new to the subject a simple wikipedia research will suffice.

First look at this definition of EMV:

> **EMV is a technical standard** for smart payment cards and for payment
>   terminals and automated teller machines that can accept them...**EMV cards are smart cards**.

Second, this is the definition of the Java Card technology:

> **Java Card refers to a software technology** that allows Java-based
>   **applications (applets)** to be run securely on **smart cards** and similar
>   small memory footprint devices.

So in the context of those definitions application and applet are equivalent terms but be careful because not all the smart card implementations are Java-based.

The key here is not to confuse technical standard concepts (those in EMV) with software technology ones (those in Java Card).

Answer (score 1):

Applet is a term used in software side and with is not linked with **EMV application term**.
Applet is a software(like OS for EMV Application) which runs on smart card to make communication and computation.

In EMV terms application is that an application runs on applet and helps to perform transactions.

Answer (score -1):

Applet is a word that is connected to Java Card, application reside in java card can be called as Applet.

EMV Chip having **application** that runs when card used in terminal,

Here application can be **Native** OR **Java Based**.

```
I've seen in some sites they were telling that application and applet are same.
```

if not go in depth, can say it is correct because applet  work as an application that reside in EMV chip and applet is a word which is frequently using for Java Card.